# deja dup wont upgrade due to error messages

Tags: upgrade, deja-dup

Have upgrades outstanding for deja dup as snap but getting error message 'unable to update, cannot refresh..snap deja dup has running apps (monitor), pids: 4078. I am running ubuntu 20.04. Regular backups are important to me (regulated business), do I need to change backup system? Help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to change backup systems.

Deja-dup is simply telling you that an update is available for it.

Snapd will continue to check for updates several times each day.

- If deja-dup happens to be running at that time, you will get the same message (it's not really an error).
- If deja-dup is NOT running, then the snap will be updated automatically. You need take no action at all. Those messages will simply stop appearing.
- If deja-dup cannot update after 14 days of trying and failing (you will notice the countdown in the messages!), snapd will terminate deja-dup, install the update, then restart deja-dup. Again, this is 100% automatic.
- Some folks want to manually control the snap update. You can do that, too. Simply pick a time when deja-dup is not running, and use the command `sudo snap refresh`.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today, `sudo snap refresh` won't show any pending updates as long as `deja-dup-monitor` is still running.

Had to run the following to get the update:

```bash
sudo snap refresh
# Output: All snaps up to date.
# snap refresh doesn't show anything because deja-dup-monitor is still running
ps faxun | grep deja
#     1000    8068  0.0  0.0 428048 10080 ?        Sl   07:22   0:00  \_ /snap/deja-dup/553/usr/libexec/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
# ...
# get the pid for deja-dup-monitor (8068) and check which user it's running with
kill 8068
# no need to sudo as deja-dup-monitor is running with our uid (1000)
sudo snap refresh
# Output: deja-dup 44.1 from Michael Terry (mterry) refreshed
```

This fixed the problem for me, after i waited for deja dup to finish todays backup but still got the error `unable to update, cannot refresh..snap deja dup has running apps (monitor), ...` from Ubuntu Software Updates tab.